# My frontend and backend not connecting on AWS cloud(getting 405 error)

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-s3, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, angular9

I have created a web application using angular 9 as a frontend and spring boot as a backend

I want to deploy this code on the AWS cloud. My web application is working fine in localhost. My application has no database connectivity. I want my web application should work on AWS but it is not working.
I have deployed frontend on s3 bucket and backend on the elastic beanstalk.
In angular application in environmenrt.prod.ts I have provided a link of the backend server.

when I run the application on AWS cloud using s3 bucket the frontend showing but as soon as I click on calculate button call should go to backend server but I am getting 405 error.

please check below error:-

POST http://fullstack-angular.s3-website.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/AgeCalculator-env.eba-23kyga2v.ap-south-1.elasticbeanstalk.com 405 (Method Not Allowed)

styles-es2015.e3fa19b4b8373bda46e5.js:1 ERROR Mi {headers: bi, status: 405, statusText: "Method Not Allowed", url: "http://fullstack-angular.s3-website.ap-south-1.ama…-env.eba-23kyga2v.ap-south-1.elasticbeanstalk.com", ok: false, …}
vn @ styles-es2015.e3fa19b4b8373bda46e5.js:1

I don't understand where I am getting wrong.Please help me out of this.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: 405 is method not allowed, have you made sure that the request you're sending is the correct type (POST, GET, PUT DELETE)?

Comment: Yes In  REST API and I am using POST method.and in angular service class also I am using POST method to send the data from frontend to backend